# Parens still being interpreted inside single quotes . .

Tags: bash

Anybody have any idea what's wrong here?

BASH isn't supposed to interpret anything inside single quotes. Why am I getting an error on the parens?

**Command from BASH script.**

```
adb push '/home/plex/media/music/file name (Album Version).mp3' '/storage/ext_sd/music/'
```

**Error Message**

```
./myscript: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./myscript: line 13: `adb push '/home/plex/media/music/file name (Album Version).mp3' '/storage/ext_sd/music/''
```

Comment: Can you verify that you still see this problem when you copy-paste that one line verbatim from your post into a new file and execute it? If not, please expand the example until it's reproducible by copy-pasting from the post. This ensures that your question captures all relevant information, and that the problem isn't with code you're not including.

Comment: Hmmm. It seems to move around. It's an export script for a plex playlist and there are several hundred lines. However I delete lines that produce no error, the error moves to a different line with parens. It's definitely something to do with special characters, but I'm not sure exactly what at this point.

Comment: Sounds like a missing quote to me. Maybe one of your songs has an apostrophe in the name. Have you run it through [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net)?

Comment: It's an error in `myscript`; what *is* line 13?

Comment: The line I posted was line 13.

Comment: that other guy: Thanks for shellcheck! I'd never heard of it.

Answer (score -2):

In case anybody else runs into this, changing the single quotes (') surrounding the source file name to double quotes (") eliminated the problem.

It turns out that it's not ADB, it's embedded single quotes. Switching to double quotes handles the embedded single quotes and the parens correctly.

Comment: Commands don't see such quotes, so it can't be an `adb` problem. The single line you've given can't possibly behave differently just by switching quote types. You've got an error somewhere else in your script that's affecting this line.

Comment: I still think you have a song called `/home/plex/whatever/Rolling Stones - I Can't Get No Satisfication.mp3` or similar where the apostrophe in `Can't` interfers with the single quotes.

Comment: That was it. The double quotes apparently enclose the single quotes correctly.

Comment: And that's why you post the *exact* line of code that produces the error, not some made-up example that doesn't produce the error you claim. You can't include a single-quote in a single-quoted string.

Comment: Note that double-quotes will allow you to embed single-quotes (apostrophes) and parentheses fine, you'll need to escape any double-quotes, dollar-signs, or backquotes in titles -- e.g. `"Charlie \"Bird\" Parker - Yardbird Suite.mp3"` and `"Ke\$ha - TiK ToK.mp3"`.

Comment: @chepner: I posted the line listed in the error message, however it turned out to not be the line that caused the error.